# Unexpected Behavior passing weak reference in lambda

Tags: asynchronous, lambda, weak-references, c++-cx

If I use this code, the function returns me null as the Resolve worked sometimes and failed sometimes (based on when this was called)

```
 Platform::WeakReference wr(this);
 Windows::Foundation::Collections::IAsyncOperation<Object1^>^ asyncTask = 
    concurrency::create_async(
    [wr, timeoutMS](concurrency::cancellation_token token) -> Object1^
    {
       if (auto refToThis = wr.Resolve<CurrentClass>())
       {
         // Do something
       }
       else return null; // The code took this path if the call was made 
                         // immediately, if the call was made from inner 
                         // page or 
                         // even after 5 sec in Main Page init – It always 
                         // worked
    }
```

Where as if I pass this reference in lambda expression it always resolves

```
 Platform::WeakReference wr(this);
 Windows::Foundation::Collections::IAsyncOperation<Object1^>^ asyncTask = 
    concurrency::create_async(
    [this, wr, timeoutMS](concurrency::cancellation_token token) -> Object1^
    {
       if (auto refToThis = wr.Resolve<CurrentClass>())
       {
         // Do something - It resolves always now
       }
       else return null; 
    }
```

Any clue why this happens? I am new to C++/Cx, I read that its not good to pass this ref in lambda expressions, but the resolve fails if I dont pass

Comment: Could you give more information as to the implementation of "Resolve<>" ? With the compilers I'm familiar with lambdas don't have a scope, so its not like you are overriding something when you pass "this"... so at a glance the behavior should remain the same.

Comment: Also, don't take my word for it, but as long as you are not planning on destroying the object while the lambda is executing (which would be bad practice for a variety of reasons anyway) I don't see an imminent problem with copying this.

Answer (score 0):

Why the second example always work:

- You are capturing `this` in the lambda closure [], means you are doing a copy of `this` inside the lambda scope. Since this is probably a `ref class` it means you increment the reference counter of the pointer on it, meaning this will not be destroyed. When resolving the weak reference, since `this` is still alive, you are able to retrieve it from the weak reference.
- In the first example, you are passing only the weak reference to the lambda closure, since you are probably working with some UI element, if this is destroyed, the weak reference resolution will return `nullptr`.

You should either pass a weak reference or directly `this` in the lambda closure, but in the case where you pass `this`, you should ensure that you will be called by this lambda in order to avoid keeping a reference on an object causing it to never be deleted, creating a memory leak.